# VS 2017 Can't display "suggestion lamp" in my own extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I can not either display a light bulb in the Visual Studio. Tried to just run an example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx). But it for some reason does not work for me.

---

Here is my code

```
    [Export(typeof(ISuggestedActionsSourceProvider))]
    [Name("Test Suggested Actions")]
    [ContentType("text")]
    internal class TestSuggestedActionsSourceProvider : ISuggestedActionsSourceProvider
    {
        [Import]
        internal ITextStructureNavigatorSelectorService NavigatorService { get; set; }

        public ISuggestedActionsSource CreateSuggestedActionsSource(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        {
            if (textBuffer == null && textView == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new TestSuggestedActionsSource(this, textView, textBuffer);
        }
    }
```

this is class TestSuggestedActionsSource

```
    internal class TestSuggestedActionsSource : ISuggestedActionsSource
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SuggestedActionsChanged;

        private readonly TestSuggestedActionsSourceProvider m_factory;
        private readonly ITextBuffer m_textBuffer;
        private readonly ITextView m_textView;

        public TestSuggestedActionsSource(TestSuggestedActionsSourceProvider testSuggestedActionsSourceProvider, 
            ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        {
            m_factory = testSuggestedActionsSourceProvider;
            m_textBuffer = textBuffer;
            m_textView = textView;
        }

        private bool TryGetWordUnderCaret(out TextExtent wordExtent)
        {
            ITextCaret caret = m_textView.Caret;
            SnapshotPoint point;

            if (caret.Position.BufferPosition > 0)
            {
                point = caret.Position.BufferPosition - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wordExtent = default(TextExtent);
                return false;
            }

            ITextStructureNavigator navigator = m_factory.NavigatorService.GetTextStructureNavigator(m_textBuffer);

            wordExtent = navigator.GetExtentOfWord(point);
            return true;
        }

        public Task<bool> HasSuggestedActionsAsync(ISuggestedActionCategorySet requestedActionCategories, SnapshotSpan range, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                TextExtent extent;
                if (TryGetWordUnderCaret(out extent))
                {  
                    return extent.IsSignificant;
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

        public IEnumerable<SuggestedActionSet> GetSuggestedActions(ISuggestedActionCategorySet requestedActionCategories, SnapshotSpan range, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            TextExtent extent;
            if (TryGetWordUnderCaret(out extent) && extent.IsSignificant)
            {
                ITrackingSpan trackingSpan = range.Snapshot.CreateTrackingSpan(extent.Span, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive);
                var upperAction = new UpperCaseSuggestedAction(trackingSpan);
                var lowerAction = new LowerCaseSuggestedAction(trackingSpan);
                SuggestedActionSet suggestedActionSet = new SuggestedActionSet(
                    PredefinedSuggestedActionCategoryNames.Any, 
                    new ISuggestedAction[] { upperAction, lowerAction });
                return new SuggestedActionSet[] { suggestedActionSet };
            }
            return Enumerable.Empty<SuggestedActionSet>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public bool TryGetTelemetryId(out Guid telemetryId)
        {
            LightBulb telemetry  
            telemetryId = Guid.Empty;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this is class LowerCaseSuggestedAction

```
internal class LowerCaseSuggestedAction : ISuggestedAction
    {
        private readonly ITrackingSpan m_span;
        private readonly string m_lower;
        private readonly string m_display;
        private readonly ITextSnapshot m_snapshot;

        public bool HasActionSets => false;
        public string DisplayText => m_display;
        public ImageMoniker IconMoniker => default(ImageMoniker);
        public string IconAutomationText => null;
        public string InputGestureText => null;
        public bool HasPreview => true;

        public LowerCaseSuggestedAction(ITrackingSpan span)
        {
            m_span = span;
            m_snapshot = span.TextBuffer.CurrentSnapshot;
            m_lower = span.GetText(m_snapshot).ToLower();
            m_display = $"Convert '{span.GetText(m_snapshot)}' to lower case";
        }

        public Task<object> GetPreviewAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Padding = new Thickness(5);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = m_lower });
            return Task.FromResult<object>(textBlock);
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<SuggestedActionSet>> GetActionSetsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<SuggestedActionSet>>(null);
        }

        public void Invoke(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            m_span.TextBuffer.Replace(m_span.GetSpan(m_snapshot), m_lower);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public bool TryGetTelemetryId(out Guid telemetryId)
        {
            // This is a sample action and doesn't participate in LightBulb telemetry  
            telemetryId = Guid.Empty;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Class UpperCaseSuggestedAction is implemented in a similar manner. Like I do everything as in the example, but the bulb does not appear at all. Here are the links that I have in my project
[image]

In reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense, parameter Copy Local is set false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem. At once I will say that some actions may be superfluous. Here, I'll just tell you what actions I did to make the project work

---

- 1. I selected my project in Solution Explorer
- 2. Through the Properties window (view> Properties Windows) in the VISX section, I set the following values:

     - a.  Include Assembly in VISX Container = true
     - b.  Include Debug Symbols in Local Deployment = true
     - c.  Include Debug Symbols in VISX Container = true
- 3. Added a library to the project Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense
- 4. For the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense library in the Properties window set Copy Local = false

Then downloaded the following Nuget packages:

- Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.6
- System.ValueTuple v4.3.0
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation v15.3.58
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers v15.8.145
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading v15.8.145
- StreamJsonRpc v1.3.23
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities v15.7.27703
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop v7.10.6071
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop v7.10.6071
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop v7.10.6072
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0 v8.0.50728
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility v15.8.525
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Data v15.6.27740
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0 v8.0.50728
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0 v10.0.30320
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0 v11.0.61031
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.EmbedInteropTypes v15.0.21
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.15.6.DesignTime v15.6.27413
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.15.3.DesignTime v15.0.26929
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.12.0 v12.0.30111
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging.Interop.14.0.DesignTime v14.3.26930
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.14.0.DesignTime v14.3.26929
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImageCatalog v15.7.27703
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging v15.7.27703

Other versions of the libraries work, but if you put them, you should look at the dependencies. They are closely related there

Next, I added the following lines to the source.extension.vsixmanifest file

```
<Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 15.0" d:Source="Installed" Version="[15.0]" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,16.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
  </Prerequisites>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" />
  </Assets>
```

PS: I hope that this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I try Жуэль Итуа's solution, but could not display a light bulb in the Visual Studio(Visual Studio Community 2017, version 15.9.7). Damn nuget package hell.

I found repository for the article, [VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/LightBulb](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/LightBulb/TestLightBulb), and it work correctly.

Comment: I did this article, but without these manipulations, nothing worked for me. In my answer, everything turned out to be necessary, except for Nuget package manipulations.